# Teams folder Referencing another Teams folder

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams folder with my Excel Data in a "DATA" channel.
My Report (in Excel) is on my Desktop. This is linked via Query into this "Data" channel (Sharepoint) source.

If I put my Desktop report into a Teams Channel called "Report" it fails on refresh.

Am I to assume that a file in a Teams Channel is not able to reference a file in another?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Are you developing any Teams app?. If yes could you please share the repro steps?

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or are you still looking for help?

Comment: Still awaiting confirmation really

Comment: Are you trying to upload the report in Teams channel and then are you facing the issue?

Comment: Let me try to explain in a different way.
File A has a data connection to other files that are stored within Teams channels.

If I use File A from my desktop it refreshes correctly.

However.
If I put File A into a Teams channel of its own and refresh, it doesn't work.

Is this any clearer?

Comment: We are mainly responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues.  

For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).  

For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).